# Finding letter grade across two classes

Tags: java

I have a program that contains five text files. These files are read in and put into different arrays. One is an array of names. The other four are arrays with test scores.

Currently, the program does create the arrays correctly. Next the program is to calculate and display the average for each test (this works fine). Then the program prompts the user for a name. If a name is found a new menu will prompt the user to select which test they want the data on. (This works fine.)

The problem: I have the main program class and another `GradeBook` class (does calculations) on another page. How do I connect the two pages together?

For example: If the `foundStudent` is 'Andrew' and it is found in `studentNameArray` and I select 1 for which test score, I want to see (`scoreOneArray`), say the number 88. My program finds 'Andrew' and '88'. What it does not do is send 'Andrew' and '88' to `GradeBook` to have the data compute test percentage (88/100) and find the corresponding letter grade (in this case 'B'). Lastly, then print students name, test score (88%), and the letter grade.

In Summary: How do I connect `Main.java` arrays to `GradeBook.java`?

Program (main):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //variables
        double test1Calculation;
        double test2Calculation;
        double test3Calculation;
        double test4Calculation;
        int i, j, k, l;
        int testOneSum = 0;
        int testTwoSum = 0;
        int testThreeSum = 0;
        int testFourSum = 0;
        int checker = 0;
        String choice;
        String token1 = "";

        //reading in files
        Scanner students = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
        Scanner TestOne = new Scanner(new File("testOne.txt"));
        Scanner TestTwo = new Scanner(new File("testTwo.txt"));
        Scanner TestThree = new Scanner(new File("testThree.txt"));
        Scanner TestFour = new Scanner(new File("testFour.txt"));

        //Creating studentName ArrayList
        List<String> studentName = new ArrayList<>();
        while (students.hasNext()) {
            //Adding name to token
            token1 = students.next();
            //Taking token string and adding it to array
            studentName.add(token1);
        }
        //Creating and adding data to studentNameArray
        String[] studentNameArray = studentName.toArray(new String[0]);

        //Creating scoreOne ArrayList
        List<Integer> scoreOne = new ArrayList<>();

        while (TestOne.hasNext()) {
            //Adding ints to token
            Integer token2 = TestOne.nextInt();
            //Taking token string and adding it to array
            scoreOne.add(token2);
        }
        //Creating and adding data to scoreOneArray
        Integer[] scoreOneArray = scoreOne.toArray(new Integer[0]);

        //Creating scoreTwo ArrayList
        List<Integer> scoreTwo = new ArrayList<>();

        while (TestTwo.hasNext()) {
            //Adding ints to token
            Integer token3 = TestTwo.nextInt();
            //Taking token string and adding it to array
            scoreTwo.add(token3);
        }
        //Creating and adding data to scoreTwoArray
        Integer[] scoreTwoArray = scoreTwo.toArray(new Integer[0]);

        //Creating scoreThree ArrayList
        List<Integer> scoreThree = new ArrayList<>();
        
        while (TestThree.hasNext()) {
            //Adding ints to token
            Integer token4 = TestThree.nextInt();
            //Taking token string and adding it to array
            scoreThree.add(token4);
        }
        //Creating and adding data to scoreThreeArray
        Integer[] scoreThreeArray = scoreThree.toArray(new Integer[0]);

        //Creating scoreFour ArrayList
        List<Integer> scoreFour = new ArrayList<>();
        
        while (TestFour.hasNext()) {
            //Adding ints to token
            Integer token5 = TestFour.nextInt();
            //Taking token string and adding it to array
            scoreFour.add(token5);
        }
        //Creating and adding data to scoreFourArray
        Integer[] scoreFourArray = scoreFour.toArray(new Integer[0]);

        //calculation for scoreOneArray Average
        for (i = 0; i < scoreOneArray.length; i++)
            testOneSum += scoreOneArray[i];
        test1Calculation = (double) testOneSum / 5;

        //calculation for scoreTwoArray Average
        for (j = 0; j < scoreTwoArray.length; j++)
            testTwoSum += scoreTwoArray[j];
        test2Calculation = (double) testTwoSum / 5;

        //calculation for scoreThreeArray Average
        for (k = 0; k < scoreThreeArray.length; k++)
            testThreeSum += scoreThreeArray[k];
        test3Calculation = (double) testThreeSum / 5;

        //calculation for scoreFourArray Average
        for (l = 0; l < scoreFourArray.length; l++)
            testFourSum += scoreFourArray[l];
        test4Calculation = (double) testFourSum / 5;

        //displaying calculation data
        System.out.println("The average for test one is: " + test1Calculation);
        System.out.println("The average for test two is: " + test2Calculation);
        System.out.println("The average for test three is: " + test3Calculation);
        System.out.println("The average for test four is: " + test4Calculation);

        //asking for student input
        Scanner studentSearch = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter student name : ");
        //searching if input is a name match to studentNameArray
        String foundStudent = studentSearch.nextLine();
        boolean found = Arrays.stream(studentNameArray).anyMatch(t -> t.equals(foundStudent));
        if (found) {
            //gather index position for further use on finding test position
            int nameIndexFinder = Arrays.asList(studentNameArray).indexOf(foundStudent);
            //printing found if found
            System.out.println(foundStudent + " is found.");
            //menu loop
            do {
                //displayed user options
                System.out.println("1. To find score for first test");
                System.out.println("2. To find score for second test");
                System.out.println("3. To find score for third test");
                System.out.println("4. To find score for fourth test");

                //menu choices
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
                choice = keyboard.next();

                if (choice.equals("1")) {
                    //searching array with corresponding user/student index position
                    int  score = scoreOneArray[nameIndexFinder];
                    GradeBook gradeBook = new GradeBook(nameIndexFinder, score);
                    //printing found test score
                    System.out.println(score);
                    checker = -1;
                } else if (choice.equals("2")) {
                    //searching array with corresponding user/student index position
                    int  score= scoreTwoArray[nameIndexFinder];
                    
                    //printing found test score
                    System.out.println(score);
                    checker = -1;
                } else if (choice.equals("3")) {
                    //searching array with corresponding user/student index position
                    int  score= scoreThreeArray[nameIndexFinder];

                    //printing found test score
                    System.out.println(score);
                    checker = -1;
                } else if (choice.equals("4")) {
                    //searching array with corresponding user/student index position
                    int  score= scoreFourArray[nameIndexFinder];

                    //printing found test score
                    System.out.println(score);

                } else {
                    //Error message
                    System.out.println("invalid choice");
                }
            }
            while (checker != -1);
        } // End of Menu Method
        else {
            //no student display message and close everything
            System.out.println(foundStudent + " is not found.");}

        //closing all read in txt files
        students.close();
        TestOne.close();
        TestTwo.close();
        TestThree.close();
        TestFour.close();
    }
}
```

Calculations(GradeBook):

```
public class GradeBook {
    private char[] letterGrade = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'};

    public char getLetterGrade(int score){
        if (score >= 90 && score <= 100){
            return letterGrade[0];
        }
        else if (score >= 80 && score <= 89){
            return letterGrade[1];
        }
        else if (score >= 70 && score <= 79){
            return letterGrade[2];
        }
        else if (score >= 60 && score <= 69){
            return letterGrade[3];
        }
        else if (score >= 0 && score <= 59){
            return letterGrade[4];
        }
        return ' ';
    }
    public void getStudent(String foundStudent, int score, String letterGrade){

        double testPercentage = (double)score / 100;
        System.out.println("Student name: " + foundStudent);
        System.out.println("Test grade: " + testPercentage);
        System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letterGrade);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. The whole entire assignment is being off-loaded. This is not how to learn to code Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class `GradeBook`

```java
public class GradeBook {
    private char[] letterGrade = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'};

    public char getLetterGrade(double avgScore) {
        if (avgScore >= 90 && avgScore <= 100) {
            return letterGrade[0];
        }
        else if (avgScore >= 80 && avgScore <= 89) {
            return letterGrade[1];
        }
        else if (avgScore >= 70 && avgScore <= 79) {
            return letterGrade[2];
        }
        else if (avgScore >= 60 && avgScore <= 69) {
            return letterGrade[3];
        }
        else if (avgScore >= 0 && avgScore <= 59) {
            return letterGrade[4];
        }
        return ' ';
    }

    public void getStudent(String foundStudent, int score) {
        double testPercentage = (double) score / 100;
        System.out.println("Student name: " + foundStudent);
        System.out.println("Test grade: " + testPercentage);
        System.out.println("Letter grade: " + getLetterGrade(score));
    }
}
```

- Removed parameter `letterGrade` since it can be obtained from parameter `score`.
- Not sure that your *percentage* calculation is correct. If the raw score is out of 100 then that already is a percentage.

Class `Main`

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    private static double getAverage(List<Integer> scores) {
        return scores.stream()
                     .mapToInt(i -> i.intValue())
                     .sum() / (double) scores.size();
    }

    private static List<Integer> loadScores(String filename) throws IOException {
        try (Stream<String> scores = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))) {
            return scores.map(score -> Integer.valueOf(score))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //variables
        double test1Calculation;
        double test2Calculation;
        double test3Calculation;
        double test4Calculation;
        int checker = 0;
        String choice;

        //Creating studentName ArrayList
        List<String> studentName = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("names.txt"));

        //Creating scoreOne ArrayList
        List<Integer> scoreOne = loadScores("testOne.txt");

        //Creating scoreTwo ArrayList
        List<Integer> scoreTwo = loadScores("testTwo.txt");

        //Creating scoreThree ArrayList
        List<Integer> scoreThree = loadScores("testThree.txt");

        //Creating scoreFour ArrayList
        List<Integer> scoreFour = loadScores("testFour.txt");

        //calculation for scoreOneArray Average
        test1Calculation = getAverage(scoreOne);

        //calculation for scoreTwoArray Average
        test2Calculation = getAverage(scoreTwo);

        //calculation for scoreThreeArray Average
        test3Calculation = getAverage(scoreThree);

        //calculation for scoreFourArray Average
        test4Calculation = getAverage(scoreFour);

        //displaying calculation data
        System.out.println("The average for test one is: " + test1Calculation);
        System.out.println("The average for test two is: " + test2Calculation);
        System.out.println("The average for test three is: " + test3Calculation);
        System.out.println("The average for test four is: " + test4Calculation);

        //asking for student input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter student name : ");
        //searching if input is a name match to studentNameArray
        String foundStudent = keyboard.nextLine();
        int nameIndexFinder = studentName.indexOf(foundStudent);
        if (nameIndexFinder >= 0) {
            //printing found if found
            System.out.println(foundStudent + " is found.");
            //menu loop
            do {
                //displayed user options
                System.out.println("1. To find score for first test");
                System.out.println("2. To find score for second test");
                System.out.println("3. To find score for third test");
                System.out.println("4. To find score for fourth test");

                //menu choices
                List<Integer> scores;
                GradeBook letterGrade = new GradeBook();
                boolean quitLoop = false;
                System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
                choice = keyboard.next();
                switch (choice) {
                    case "-1":
                        quitLoop = true;
                        scores = null;
                        break;
                    case "1":
                        scores = scoreOne;
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        scores = scoreTwo;
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        scores = scoreThree;
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        scores = scoreFour;
                        break;
                    default:
                        scores = null;
                }
                if (scores != null) {
                    letterGrade.getStudent(foundStudent, scores.get(nameIndexFinder));
                }
                else {
                    if (quitLoop) {
                        break;
                    }
                    //Error message
                    System.out.println("invalid choice");
                }
            }
            while (checker != -1);
        } // End of Menu Method
        else {
            //no student display message and close everything
            System.out.println(foundStudent + " is not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

- Use methods rather than repeating code.
- Use single `Scanner` instance.
- No need for array. Use method [get](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#get(int)) of interface `java.util.List`
- Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
- You can [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html) on strings.
- I believe you have a bug in the `do-while` loop. The loop never terminates.

Comment: Just a heads up that the OP may be a possible help vampire as per [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71566013/) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71565804/). They're off-loading the entire assignment piecemeal using sock-puppet accounts.